# Get int value from enum with where clause

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have this enum :

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2,
    D = 3,
    E = 4
}
```

I have a `List<string> {"A", "C", "E"}`

I'd like make a query on `MyEnum` to get back the int values as a `List<int>` Here the result should be 0,2,4

Same question but when I have a `List<int> {0, 2, 4}` I'd like get back a `List<string>` with `A,C,E`

Do you have an idea how do this in .NET 4.7 ?

Thanks,

Comment: What should happen when values in the list(s) do not exist in the enum?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I am sure the values exist

Answer (score 0):

From `names` to `values`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<string> names = new List<string>() { "A", "C", "E" };

// If there's no guarantee that name is a correct enum name
// use TryParse instead of Parse
var values = names
  .Select(name => Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), name)))
  .ToList();
```

From `values` to `names`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<int> values = new List<int>() { 0, 2, 4 };

var names = values
  .Select(value => ((MyEnum)value).ToString())
  .ToList();
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/URUhJF)

Comment: On names to value, I get an error on 'name" in the Parse 'cannot convert enum to string)

Comment: @Kris-I: please, fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/URUhJF

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure they exist you can parse them and use `List.ConvertAll`:

```
List<string> list = new() { "A", "C", "E" };
List<int> result = list.ConvertAll(s => (int)(MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), s));
```

to get the strings back, so the opposite way:

```
list = result.ConvertAll(i => ((MyEnum)i).ToString());
```